# Host and Application Properties in Project

Tags: office-js, ms-project

I see in the docu https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/context that 'host' and 'platform' properties should be supported in Project, but I can't find these properties in the Office.context object.

I've currently the 1712 (Build 8813.1000) Office Insider version installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in Project. I don't know of any immediate plans to do so. I suggest you add a user voice request to ask for the feature [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)

Comment: Thanks but that's weird, because its on the shared context and all other platforms are supporting it.
Then you should also correct the documentation [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/context.md) because it is said that project is also supporting it